# how to cut a picture (not cropping) with php

Tags: php

I want to cut out part of the photo without stretch it.
Something like the photo I posted, cut out the red part and get photo number 2
With a width of 150px and height of 100px and cuting from top left of photo
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtLUc.png)

I tried to do it with this code but it didn't work. 
This codes separates part of the image, but does not do so from the top left of the image.

```
    function resizejpeg($dir, $newdir, $img, $max_w, $max_h, $th_w, $th_h)
{
    // set destination directory
    if (!$newdir) $newdir = $dir;

    // get original images width and height
    list($or_w, $or_h, $or_t) = getimagesize($dir.$img);

    // make sure image is a jpeg
    if ($or_t == 2) {

        // obtain the image's ratio
        $ratio = ($or_h / $or_w);

        // original image
        $or_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($dir.$img);

        // resize image?
        if ($or_w > $max_w || $or_h > $max_h) {

            // resize by height, then width (height dominant)
            if ($max_h < $max_w) {
                $rs_h = $max_h;
                $rs_w = $rs_h / $ratio;
            }
            // resize by width, then height (width dominant)
            else {
                $rs_w = $max_w;
                $rs_h = $ratio * $rs_w;
            }

            // copy old image to new image
            $rs_image = imagecreatetruecolor($rs_w, $rs_h);
            imagecopyresampled($rs_image, $or_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $rs_w, $rs_h, $or_w, $or_h);
        }
        // image requires no resizing
        else {
            $rs_w = $or_w;
            $rs_h = $or_h;

            $rs_image = $or_image;
        }

        // generate resized image
        imagejpeg($rs_image, $newdir.$img, 100);

        $th_image = imagecreatetruecolor($th_w, $th_h);

        // cut out a rectangle from the resized image and store in thumbnail
        $new_w = (($rs_w / 2) - ($th_w / 2));
        $new_h = (($rs_h / 2) - ($th_h / 2));

        imagecopyresized($th_image, $rs_image, 0, 0, $new_w, $new_h, $rs_w, $rs_h, $rs_w, $rs_h);

        // generate thumbnail
        imagejpeg($th_image, $newdir.'thumb_'.$img, 100);

        return true;
    }

    // Image type was not jpeg!
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

$dir = './';
$img = '1.jpg';

$size = getimagesize($img);
$width = $size[0];
$height = $size[1];

resizejpeg($dir, '', $img, $width, $height, 150, 100);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't understand correctly what you mean, but based on your description you are trying to get the image no 2 which means you are trying to crop an image. If that your mean, maybe this code will help

```php
function crop($image_path, $output_path, $x, $y, $width, $height) {
    // load image
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($image_path);
    // crop the image
    $cropped_image = imagecrop($image, [
        'x' => $x, 
        'y' => $y, 
        'width' => $width,
        'height' => $height
        ]
    );
    // save it
    imagejpeg($cropped_image, $output_path);
}
```

you can use it like this

```php
// input image path
$image = "img.jpg";
// output image path
$output = "crop_img.jpg";
// crop it from (0,0)
crop($image, $output, 0, 0, 150, 100);
```